# Estilo de Checkbox alterando estilo em label. Como arrumar?

Tags: css, css3

Bom Dia!

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
 <div style="float:left;">
   <label class="labelPequeno">Oportunidade</label><input type="checkbox" id="oportunidade" name="oportunidade" />
 </div>

 <div style="width:85px;height:40px; float:left;"></div>    

 <div style="float:left;">
   <label class="labelPequeno">Cobertura</label><input type="checkbox" id="cobertura" name="cobertura" />
 </div>

 <div style="width:85px;height:40px; float:left;"></div>    

 <div style="float:left;">
   <label class="labelPequeno">Suite</label><input type="text" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" class="typeTextPequeno" maxlength="15" id="suite" name="suite"  /> <br /> <br />
 </div>
```

A ideia é colocar nesta ordem:

```
 1 label + 1 Checkbox + 1 espaço + 1 label + 1 chekbox + 1 espaço + 1 label + 1 type text
```

Estou usando esse `css` para o `label`:

```
label
{
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px; 
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

e este `css` para o `checkbox`

```
input[type=checkbox]
{
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
```

O problema é que onde tem `chekbox` os `labeis` estão sendo exibidos abaixados em relação à linha.

Como concertar?

problema está na linha que tem : `Oportunidade`, `Cobertura` e `Suite`

Veja na figura abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente adicionar isso ao style do LABEL:

```
float: left;
```

Verifique se satisfaz a sua necessidade.

Comment: Obrigado, adicionei este estilo apenas aos 2 labels problemáticos. rsrs

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona esse código CSS.

```
label.labelPequeno {
    line-height: normal;
}
```

Está acontecendo este problema por causa do line-height que ele pega da classe label.

Veja o exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzxbp7zv/).

Caso mesmo assim não fique ajustado, você pode alterar para um valor no `line-height: normal;`, da classe labelPequeno, para que fique do seu jeito.